# RecordRTC not works inside Angular Library

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-library, recordrtc

I have an angular library written in v15 with recordRTC v5.6.2 package. I am trying to use recordRTC inside a service but it gives a typeError that does not occurs in a regular angular project (not a library). My service is:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as RecordRTC from 'recordrtc';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RecorderService {
  private stream: MediaStream;
  private recorder;
  constructor() { }

  public initializeRecorder(): Promise<boolean> {
    return navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      audio: true,
      video: false,
    }).then(async (stream) => {
      this.stream = stream;
      this.recorder = new RecordRTC(stream, {
        type: 'audio'
      });
      this.recorder.startRecording();
      return true;
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log('error initializing recorder ----> ', err);
      return false;
    });
  }
}
```

And when i try to run the "initializeRecorder" method it falls to my catch block giving the error:

```
TypeError: (recordrtc__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___namespace_cache || recordrtc__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___namespace_cache) is not a constructor
```

The same code snippet when i run it at a regular angular 15 project works normally, but inside the angular library it does not work.

Comment: Have you listed recordRTC in `peerDependencies` as opposed to `dependencies`?

Comment: can you try removing the 'new' in the line `new RecordRTC(...`

Comment: Yes, i have listed recordrtc as a peerdependency.
Removing the 'new' gives a type error (value of type 'typeof RecordRTC' is not callable. Did you mean to include 'new'?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, you did not install and import correctly. To install and use this library, whether, for audio or video, you can follow these two links:

**1- Audio Recording using Record RTC: [link](https://moneychaudhary.medium.com/how-to-implement-audio-recording-using-record-rtc-in-angular-2-de1967328c38).**

and

**2- RecordRTC Video Recording with Angular: [link](https://medium.com/@SumanthShankar/integrate-recordrtc-with-angular-2-typescript-942c9c4ca93f).**

Comment: The second link worked for me. Thanks! But i still doesn´t understand why my previous implementation worked inside a regular angular app but not inside an angular library. But this solution worked for me.